# Java 7: using URLClassLoader not working anymore

Tags: classloader, java-7, self-contained

my problem is, that my code which was working on Java6 does not work any more.
Since my app needs to load jar's at runtime (plugins), i wrote myselt a simple class deriving from URLClassLoader like this

```
public class MyClassLoader extends java.net.URLClassLoader {

/** Creates a new instance of URLClassLoader */
public MyClassLoader(java.net.URL url) 
{
    super(new java.net.URL[]{url},ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
}

public void addURL(java.net.URL url)
{
    super.addURL(url);
}}
```

So if i want load a jar, i simply call addURL(pathToJar) and load that class via

```
Class.forName(myClass, true, myClassLoader)
```

This worked like a charm running on Java6.
Now i decided to make a self contained java app in Java7.
When I start the app, the jar's also get loaded at runtime, but if there's a class inside which derives from a class that is inside the classpath (not in the plugin jar) i get a ClassCastException.

So i guess something has changed in Java7.
At the moment I'm using Java7_u13 on OSX.
Can any one give me a hint on what I should do, to get the old behaviour back? Searching the net didn't get me any help yet.

Many thanks in advance.

Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile i found the solution to my problem. I just used the 'wrong' classloader as the parent. Everything now works fine if i replace

```
super(new java.net.URL[]{url},ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

with

```
super(new java.net.URL[]{url},MyClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
```

Greetings, -chris-